# How to find/detect hidden files inside JPEG file?

Tags: command-line, jpeg, embedding, steganography

I'm trying to find out what is a good way to detect whether an image file has other files hidden inside it?

related link:

- [Hide files inside of JPEG images](http://lifehacker.com/282119/hide-files-inside-of-jpeg-images) at lifehacker

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Simple methods**

**Method via ImageMagick/convert tool**

Use ImageMagick command tool `convert` to find the differences between the original file and converted one. E.g.

```
$ convert original.jpg converted.jpg  # this is an ImageMagick command
$ ls -l original.jpg converted.jpg
  667228 original.jpg
  648515 converted.jpg
```

Then you can compare the binary file, see: [How do I compare binary files in Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/125376/87805)

**Method via strings**

Look for any suspicious content via `strings`. It will print any printable strings in a file which could indicate some hidden files, messages or content. E.g.:

```
$ strings -10 image.jpg
```

Example image: [The original image with hidden message which started the Cicada 3301](http://web.archive.org/web/20150520094314/http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cicada_3001_Final.jpg)

---

**Advanced methods**

**Method via hexdump**

Every JPEG file starts by SOI (Start of image) with binary value of `0xFFD8` and it is terminated by EOI Marker (End of image) which has the binary value of `0xFFD9`.

Therefore you may try to check for any extra content after EOI marker. In example:

```
hexdump -C image.jpg  | less +/"ff d9"
hexdump -C image.jpg  | more +/"ff d9"
```

**Method via xdd**

Use `xdd` command-line based tool with `tr` and `sed` to print the content after EOI Marker.

In example:

```
xxd -c1 -p image.jpg | tr "\n" " " | sed -n -e 's/.*\( ff d9 \)\(.*\).*/\2/p' | xxd -r -p
```

Read more: [How to dump part of binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451890/how-to-dump-part-of-binary-file) at SE

---

Related:

- [How to find hidden files inside image files (Jpg/Gif/Png) [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451109/how-to-find-hidden-files-inside-image-files-jpg-gif-png) at StackOverflow
- [Finding hidden files (video files) within an image [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469084/finding-hidden-files-video-files-within-an-image) at StackOverflow
- [JPEG format and Marker](http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html)
- [Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) at Wikipedia